# strange behaviour of format flag in boost::posix_time

Tags: c++, boost

I have a string containing two time stamps. I am trying to convert both the time stamps into boost::posix_time::ptime.

the string format looks like:
`"ASTRO20220923.1435+0000-20220923.1440+0000"`
the format I use in `boost::posix_time::time_input_facet` for the second time stamp is `".*+A%Y%m%d.%H%M"`.

I get correct output but i don’t understand how i get it. On searching the format flags i cannot find any flag as `".*"` or `"+A"`. Can someone please help explain why this behaviour is happening?

[[LIVE on coliru]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cf1429c2d738344)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
 
int main()
{
    std::string timeStr = "ASTRO20220923.1435+0000-20220923.1440+0000";
    std::stringstream ss;
    
    boost::posix_time::ptime pTimeStart;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("ASTRO%Y%m%d.%H%M.*")));
    ss << timeStr;
    ss >> pTimeStart;

    std::cout << "START: " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(pTimeStart) << std::endl;

    boost::posix_time::ptime pTimeEnd;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet(".*+A%Y%m%d.%H%M")));
    ss << timeStr;
    ss >> pTimeEnd;

    std::cout << "END  : " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(pTimeEnd) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Boost input facets treat *any* non-field input character as a wildcard: it matches *any* input character. This goes for control codes and even embedded NUL characters. [None of this is documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260825/strange-behaviour-of-format-flag-in-boostposix-time/75261009#comment132810305_75261009), and frankly seems dubious. See this ludicrous test program:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4adeaeff92d99211)**

Which shows all chosen wildcards succeeding, no matter how far-fetched:

```
DEBUG : '.....%Y%m%d.%H%M..', '....%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'AAAAA%Y%m%d.%H%MAA', 'AAAA%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'BBBBB%Y%m%d.%H%MBB', 'BBBB%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'CCCCC%Y%m%d.%H%MCC', 'CCCC%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'DDDDD%Y%m%d.%H%MDD', 'DDDD%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'EEEEE%Y%m%d.%H%MEE', 'EEEE%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'fffff%Y%m%d.%H%Mff', 'ffff%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'ggggg%Y%m%d.%H%Mgg', 'gggg%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'hhhhh%Y%m%d.%H%Mhh', 'hhhh%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'iiiii%Y%m%d.%H%Mii', 'iiii%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'jjjjj%Y%m%d.%H%Mjj', 'jjjj%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'kkkkk%Y%m%d.%H%Mkk', 'kkkk%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'lllll%Y%m%d.%H%Mll', 'llll%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'mmmmm%Y%m%d.%H%Mmm', 'mmmm%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : 'nnnnn%Y%m%d.%H%Mnn', 'nnnn%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '11111%Y%m%d.%H%M11', '1111%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '22222%Y%m%d.%H%M22', '2222%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '33333%Y%m%d.%H%M33', '3333%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '44444%Y%m%d.%H%M44', '4444%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '55555%Y%m%d.%H%M55', '5555%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '66666%Y%m%d.%H%M66', '6666%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '77777%Y%m%d.%H%M77', '7777%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '88888%Y%m%d.%H%M88', '8888%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '99999%Y%m%d.%H%M99', '9999%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '00000%Y%m%d.%H%M00', '0000%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '_____%Y%m%d.%H%M__', '____%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '-----%Y%m%d.%H%M--', '----%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '/////%Y%m%d.%H%M//', '////%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '?????%Y%m%d.%H%M??', '????%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '*****%Y%m%d.%H%M**', '****%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '\\\\\\\\\\%Y%m%d.%H%M\\\\', '\\\\\\\\%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '"""""%Y%m%d.%H%M""', '""""%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : "'''''%Y%m%d.%H%M''", "''''%Y%m%d.%H%M" START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '[[[[[%Y%m%d.%H%M[[', '[[[[%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : ']]]]]%Y%m%d.%H%M]]', ']]]]%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '(((((%Y%m%d.%H%M((', '((((%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : ')))))%Y%m%d.%H%M))', '))))%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '&&&&&%Y%m%d.%H%M&&', '&&&&%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '^^^^^%Y%m%d.%H%M^^', '^^^^%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '$$$$$%Y%m%d.%H%M$$', '$$$$%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '#####%Y%m%d.%H%M##', '####%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '@@@@@%Y%m%d.%H%M@@', '@@@@%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '!!!!!%Y%m%d.%H%M!!', '!!!!%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '     %Y%m%d.%H%M  ', '    %Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '




%Y%m%d.%H%M

', '



%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '




%Y%m%d.%H%M

', '



%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '                   %Y%m%d.%H%M     ', '                %Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
DEBUG : '%Y%m%d.%H%M', '%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   1400-Jan-01 00:00:00 END: 1400-Jan-01 00:00:00 IGNORED: ASTRO20220923.1435+0000-20220923.1440+0000 (true)
DEBUG : '%Y%m%d.%H%M', '%Y%m%d.%H%M' START:   2022-Sep-23 14:35:00 END: 2022-Sep-23 14:40:00 IGNORED: +0000 (true)
```

### Parsing With Spirit

To parse the start/end period with the given format, I would not use facets in the first place, because none of the format appears locale-aware. The fact that you use `ptime` (not `local_date_time`) confirms that the time-zone indication (+0000) is not significant.

So, here's what you could write:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fc92a442637032f)**

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::posix_time::ptime;

namespace Astro {
    namespace Parser {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using Part   = unsigned short;
        using Parts  = std::tuple<Part, Part, Part, Part, Part>;

        static auto const dig4 = x3::uint_parser<Part, 10, 4, 4>{};
        static auto const dig2 = x3::uint_parser<Part, 10, 2, 2>{};
        static auto const timeformat
            = x3::rule<struct partsformat_, Parts>{"timeformat"}
            = dig4 >> dig2 >> dig2 >> '.' >> dig2 >> dig2 >> "+0000";

        static auto const period //
            = "ASTRO" >> Parser::timeformat >> "-" >> Parser::timeformat >> x3::eoi;
    } // namespace Parser

    ptime to_ptime(Parser::Parts const& p) {
        auto [yyyy, mm, dd, HH, MM] = p;
        return {{yyyy, mm, dd}, boost::posix_time::hours(HH) + boost::posix_time::minutes(MM)};
    }

    struct Period {
        ptime start, end;
    };

    Period parsePeriod(std::string_view input) {
        Parser::Parts s, e;
        auto both = std::tie(s, e);

        if (parse(begin(input), end(input), Parser::period, both))
            return {to_ptime(s), to_ptime(e)};

        throw std::runtime_error("parsePeriod");
    }
}

int main() {
    auto [s, e] = Astro::parsePeriod("ASTRO20220923.1435+0000-20220923.1440+0000");

    std::cout << "start: " << s << "\n";
    std::cout << "end:   " << e << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
start: 2022-Sep-23 14:35:00
end:   2022-Sep-23 14:40:00
```

If you really need stream support, you can build that on top:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00363373df374197)**

```
template <typename It>
bool parsePeriod(It& f, It l, Period& into, bool require_eoi = true) {
    Parser::Parts s, e;
    auto parts = std::tie(s, e);

    bool ok = parse(f, l, Parser::period , parts);
    if (ok) {
        into = {to_ptime(s), to_ptime(e)};
        if (require_eoi)
            ok = ok && (f == l);
    }
    return ok;
}

Period parsePeriod(std::string_view input) {
    Period result;
    auto   f = begin(input), l = end(input);
    if (!parsePeriod(f, l, result, true))
        throw std::runtime_error("parsePeriod");
    return result;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Period& period) {
    auto saved = is.flags();

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(is >> std::noskipws), l;
    if  (!parsePeriod(f, l, period , false))
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

    is.flags(saved);
    return is;
}
```

Which allows you to use it in the same way:

```
std::istringstream iss("ASTRO20220923.1435+0000-20220923.1440+0000");

Astro::Period p;
if (iss >> p) {
    std::cout << "start: " << p.start << "\n";
    std::cout << "end:   " << p.end << "\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Parse error\n";
}
```

Printing

```
start: 2022-Sep-23 14:35:00
end:   2022-Sep-23 14:40:00
```

### BENCHMARKS!

To drive home the point how utterly inefficient the input facet is, I made a benchmark.

It includes the

- question code (using boost input facet)
- naively using the facet but with some of the issues from the question removed
- throwing all the Clever™ tricks to optimize at the boost input facet
- my Spirit X3 version

Here's the timings (using [Nonius](https://github.com/libnonius/nonius)): *(click for interactive chart with detail samples)*

[image]

Benchmark code: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c3bba126e1da30)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace FacetQuestionCode {
    // code from the question, already removing output and one unnecessary allocation (`timeStr` is now a
    // string view)
    //
    //  - still has unnecessary facet instantiation/destruction, locale creation/destruction, spurious double
    // stream insertion and no error detection
    auto parsePeriod(std::string_view timeStr) {
        std::stringstream ss;

        boost::posix_time::ptime pTimeStart;
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("ASTRO%Y%m%d.%H%M.*")));
        ss << timeStr;
        ss >> pTimeStart;

        // std::cout << "START: " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(pTimeStart) << std::endl;

        boost::posix_time::ptime pTimeEnd;
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet(".*+A%Y%m%d.%H%M")));
        ss << timeStr;
        ss >> pTimeEnd;

        // std::cout << "END  : " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(pTimeEnd) << std::endl;
        return std::pair(pTimeStart, pTimeEnd);
    }
}

namespace FacetNaive {
    // undocumented behaviour, error-prone because not-specifc
    auto parsePeriod(std::string_view input) {
        std::stringstream ss{std::string(input)};
        auto*             facet = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet();
        ss.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), facet));

        boost::posix_time::ptime s, e;
        facet->format("?????%Y%m%d.%H%M??");   ss >> s;
        facet->format("????%Y%m%d.%H%M?????"); ss >> e;

        return std::pair(s, e);
    }
}

namespace FacetClever {
    // undocumented behaviour, error-prone because not-specifc
    // very dirty optimization tricks
    auto parsePeriod(std::string_view input) {
        thread_local std::stringstream ss;
        thread_local boost::posix_time::time_input_facet* facet = [&] {
            auto tmp = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet();
            ss.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
            ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), tmp));
            return tmp;
        }();

        ss.clear();
        ss.str(std::string(input));

        boost::posix_time::ptime s, e;
        facet->format("?????%Y%m%d.%H%M??");   ss >> s;
        facet->format("????%Y%m%d.%H%M?????"); ss >> e;

        return std::pair(s, e);
    }
}

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace SpiritX3 {
    namespace Parser {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using Part   = unsigned short;
        using Parts  = std::tuple<Part, Part, Part, Part, Part>;

        static auto const dig4 = x3::uint_parser<Part, 10, 4, 4>{};
        static auto const dig2 = x3::uint_parser<Part, 10, 2, 2>{};
        static auto const timeformat
            = x3::rule<struct partsformat_, Parts>{"timeformat"}
            = dig4 >> dig2 >> dig2 >> '.' >> dig2 >> dig2 >> "+0000";

        static auto const period //
            = "ASTRO" >> Parser::timeformat >> "-" >> Parser::timeformat >> x3::eoi;
    } // namespace Parser

    boost::posix_time::ptime to_ptime(Parser::Parts const& p) {
        auto [yyyy, mm, dd, HH, MM] = p;
        return {{yyyy, mm, dd}, boost::posix_time::hours(HH) + boost::posix_time::minutes(MM)};
    }

    struct Period {
        boost::posix_time::ptime start, end;
    };

    Period parsePeriod(std::string_view input) {
        Parser::Parts s, e;
        auto both = std::tie(s, e);

        if (parse(begin(input), end(input), Parser::period, both))
            return {to_ptime(s), to_ptime(e)};

        throw std::runtime_error("parsePeriod");
    }
}

#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>

constexpr auto input = "ASTRO20220923.1435+0000-20220923.1440+0000";
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("FacetQuestionCode", []{ FacetQuestionCode::parsePeriod(input); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("FacetNaive",        []{ FacetNaive::parsePeriod(input);        })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("FacetClever",       []{ FacetClever::parsePeriod(input);       })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("SpiritX3",          []{ SpiritX3::parsePeriod(input);          })
```

Note how:

- the `FacetNaive` is already 2x faster than the `FacetQuestionCode`
- the Too Clever By Far(TM) optimized version using facets is still 20x slower than Spirit
- all the facet versions suffer from lack of specificity and rely on undocumented behavior
- The Spirit version is effectively >11,000x faster than the original code, also with the smalles relative deviations

The choice really doesn't seem too hard.

Comment: Wait a second. Are you expecting two parse **two** timestamps. Let me look at that a bit more closely.

Comment: yeah i am expecting to get two time stamps from the single timeStr.

Comment: Yeah. I would take the "ASTRO{}-{}" part out of the facet. In fact, since the format is fixed and requires no calendar/locale specific logic for parsing, I'd parse it without IO-streams: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fc92a442637032f This gives you full flexibility regarding the expected format.

Comment: Expanded the answer to show (include `istream` support)

Comment: thanks for giving the example without IO-stream. My final goal is to compare multiple timestamps and order them from newest to oldest.

But can you please explain a bit more why you would not use the way i used in the question ? Is it a bug that reusing the stream gives correct date and this behaviour may not be constant?

Comment: Yeah. It's undocumented. The docs [vaguely](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#:~:text=Many%20of%20the%20format%20flags%20this%20new%20system%20uses%20for%20output%20are%20those%20used%20by%20strftime(...)%2C%20but%20not%20all) refer to [strftime(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) which also doesn't mention it. Neither does the logical extension [strptime(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html): ...

Comment: "_ All other characters in the format string must have
       a matching character in the input string, except for whitespace,
       which matches zero or more whitespace characters in the input
       string"_ (quote). So all you can do is ... dive into the implementation, cross your fingers, pray and have tests, but why would you? It's gonna be dog slow anyways.

Comment: A dive into the code base confirmed that *any* non-field format character will match *any* input character. This even goes for control codes, NUL, etc. See these ludicrous test cases: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4adeaeff92d99211 . I wouldn't want to depend on any of that. (But the test bed shows some pretty important optimization and improved error handling): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5cd8ca69796518f

Comment: Updated the answer with the information. I just wanted to know the performance difference. So I added benchmarks. The non-facet approach is over 11,000x faster :) I included some optimizations on the facet approach (that are only ~60x times faster in total, and they're TooClever(TM) for my taste)